# How to make a very circular heart in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes

I want a perfectly round heart if that makes any sense. My idea was to start with a circle. Then I wanted to give it a small widows peak at the top. This would pinch a point into the space of the circle. Next I want to pinch a point out of the circle at the bottom.

I am having a hard time describing what I want to I can't fine the right documentation. I thought I could add two anchor points one on either side of the 12 o'clock anchor point of a circle even spaced and then drag the 12 o'clock anchor point to create the widows peak.

If for any reason you understand what i mena please help lol.

[image]

Comment: We understand the letters you used in your terrada. Unfortunately, the voluminous verbiage prevent us from more specific understanding, thus you should try to organize the letters in slightly more sophisticated order or/and even add some pothooks and hangers to them...

Comment: a sketch would help enormously

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.. if you envision what you want.... is there some hurdle to you at least attempting that in Illustrator? Then posting what you have, and where you are having trouble? Or, are you just asking for a step by step tutorial without even trying yourself first??? We are **not** a "tutorial on demand" site.

Comment: I uploaded an image. I apologize for my amature question. I am brand new to design, AI, and this is my first question here ever.

Comment: Have you even tried doing this in Illustrator?

Comment: @Scott my question is asking how to do this in Illustrator. That is what I meant by the title of my question.

Comment: Leon, I applaud the zest to learn. However, this is **not** a "tutorial on demand" site. Per the site guidelines, questions should show **some effort**. Your question could essentially be answered by typing it into google. It shows no effort and is lazy overall.  My desire is not to target you... it's to keep the level of questions *useful* to more members than just the one asking for a tutorial. **Rudimentary** exploration of Illustrator tools would also achieve what you are seeking. It's not rocket science.

Comment: I am not familiar with Illustrator at all. It is my first week using it. However I Googled and played with all the tools for about 8 hours total before asking here. I suppose I should refrain from asking anymore questions until I am an expert myself.

Comment: You do **not** need to be anywhere near an expert. However, http://tv.adobe.com/ has basic tutorials on how to use applications. At the very least, you should explore tutorials before asking someone to write you one on demand.

Comment: @Scott thank you. My inability to find an answer was not knowing terminology. I did put effort into this first. I actually followed a tutorial to make a heart shape, it made a more traditional heart shape that did not fit my vision. I then thought of taking a circle and doing what the sketch implies. I tried the "Add anchor tool" I tried the pencil tool, I tried every tool and read and watched several resources. Finally in desperation I asked here. I do appreciate you taking the time to clarify the rules of this site and your passion to enforce them. I have learned about Stack Exchange today.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28919/discussion-between-leon-francis-shelhamer-and-scott).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be a little challenging if you aren't used to using Illustrator's Pen tool or working with paths in general, but here's one way to do it.

1. **Draw a circle.** With the Ellipse tool selected, hold Shift and drag to draw your circle (shift will constrain your proportions and make it perfectly round)
   [image]
2. **Add four extra points to your circle.** Select the Pen tool, and hover over the top edge of your circle until you see a little plus appear. Click to add extra points at the top of your circle, one on each side of the center point. Repeat on the bottom.
   [image]
3. **Pull your top center point down.** Using the Direct Selection tool (the white arrow), select your top center point and drag it down.

   [image: direct selection tool]
   [image]
4. **Convert the center point to an angle.** Select the Anchor Point tool (it is buried under the Pen tool) and click on your top center point. This will make it come to a sharp point.

   [image: anchor point tool] 
   [image]
5. **Smooth out your path's curves.** This is the trickiest part. Select a one of your new points with the Direct Selection tool to bring up that points Bezier curve handle bars. Drag the ends of these handles around to get your curve just right. 
   [image]
6. Repeat steps 3-5 at the bottom of your shape.
   [image] 
   [image]
   [image]
7. **Refine your curves.** Use the Direct selection tool to select individual points and drag the handle bars around until you're happy with the shape's look. 
   [image]

Good luck!

Comment: Always a shame when a *great answer* is added to a *completely* lazy (close-worthy) question. :)

Comment: @Scott  :) I remember not knowing the right terms to search for or the right questions to ask. I figured something like this could help more than one person someday.

Comment: @Scott, I'm sorry my question does not stand up to your professional requirements. But I am certain nothing can make a good answer a shame. I applaud Vicki for her amazing answer and I am truly grateful. I will work hard to remember where I started so that I can be as kind to new comers as Vicki

Comment: sorry but this is a very convoluted answer, a heart only needs 4 anchor points

Comment: I was going off what they showed in their sketch. Your solution is a great option as well.